# Access dynamically created items using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where some html is being dynamically added to the page.

This is the html and javascript that is created:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    </script>

    <a id="btn">Button</a>
</div>
```

Looking in my Firebug console, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: $("#btn") is null

jQuery is being loaded on the page initially.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what's added dynamically ? how ?

Comment: Your code should not result in that *TypeError* even if the DOM is not ready. Are you also using `prototypejs`?

Comment: `TypeError: $("#btn") is null` is not because of dynamic elements.. Tell us what you mean by dynamic elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to bind `on()` (or the events defined within the `on()` method, to an element that exists in the DOM at the point at which the jQuery was run. Usually this is on `$(document).ready()` or similar.

Bind to the closest element in which the `$('#btn')` element will be appended that exists in the DOM on page-load/DOM ready.

Assuming that you're loading the `$('#btn')` into the `#container` `div` (for example), to give:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="btn">Button text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#btn', function(){
    alert('Button clicked!');
});
```

Comment: I don't think that is an issue here.. `TypeError: $("#btn") is null` is not something thrown on dynamic elements.

Comment: @Vega: I hadn't taken proper notice of that error. Hmm. Presumably instead, then, the element is not being selected properly in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.on` to wire up the event to your button.  Check this SO answer:

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#btn', function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
})
```

Edit: I added the document ready code, you'll want to make sure you do that.

Fixed.

Comment: That syntax wouldn't bind to dynamically added nodes

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for .on here which will bind the click event to dynamically added nodes.

```
$("#parent_container").on("click", "#btn", function () {
    alert("hello")
})
```

the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: That syntax wouldn't bind to dynamically added nodes

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. Been looking at backbonejs for too long, got them mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div>
     <a id="btn">Button</a>
</div>
 <script>

    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `<script>` is just enough. Still if `#btn` is the dyn. generated one, this won't work :)

Comment: This won't help with dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are attaching the event to the button before the button is being created.

Correct version is:

```
  <div>
       <a id="btn">Button</a>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           $('#btn').click(function() {
              alert("Hello");
           });
       </script>            
  </div>
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function of jQuery

Comment: As a note about .live() from the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."